# Как применять переменную в less?

Tags: less

```css
.generate-image(@n) when (@n < 4) {
    .portfolio__item:nth-child(@{n}) {
        background: url(../img/portfolio-image@{n}.png);
    }
    .generate-image (@n + 1);
}
.generate-image(1);
```

Данный код в моём представлении должен был превратиться в код, который н-ному элементу задаёт н-ную картинку в качестве фона, но ничего не выходит
Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

поместите путь до картинки в кавычки. `'../img/portfolio-image@{n}.png'`